# Could you pull from a EC2 or EB application?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have multiple computers (Macbook Pro, iMac, Mac Pro), and have some projects shared between these computers. Currently I use internally network to do pull requests between computers on applications. But I would love it if I can use EC2 or EB as a "git repository" so I can even pull remotely. I don't think this feature is officially supported by AWS but I think in theory it can be done if I could, for example, download the remote .git folder from AWS.

Comment: @scrowler Can you make it an answer. I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [AWS's CodeCommit](http://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) - it sounds exactly what you're looking for.

If you need more of a UI, you could have your own EC2 instance running a source control software like [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash), or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [AWS CodeCommit](http://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/)

It is also possible to setup your own git server and you can surely do that on EC2.

You can do that using an `https`, `ssh` protocol or mounting a remote file system which would be on EC2.

If you are looking for a package to do that, there are many available and you can use them.

[Here](http://crosbymichael.com/setup-your-own-git-server-over-ssh.html) is something to get you started.